# Glassfish server log flodding with Interrupting idle Thread

Tags: java, spring, glassfish

We have deployed an Spring MVC application on `GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2`. Server log is on warning level, so after deployment I observed that lots of server.log files are generated almost 95-97% of logs are filled with:

> [#|2015-10-15T20:19:20.995+0530|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=13;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GRIZZLY0023: Interrupting idle Thread: http-thread-pool-80(7).|#]

While google search I come to know about issue posted on [JIRA](https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1339) and one patch added on it, I haven't tried that patch yet but I wanted to know the reason behind this `WARNING`. Some doubts are in my mind :

1. Is this warning safe to ignore?
2. Why glassfish service is interrupting threads? what is actually
   happening in glassfish service?
3. How can I avoid this warning to generate? and what will cause if I
   ignore this (what will be the impact)?

Answer (score 1):

1) If your CPU usage is high it is not safe to ignore, as it could cause the death of your server

2) Most probably you see this problem because servlet/webapp processes
request longer than 15mins (by default).

3) If above-mentioned is ok for you, you will need to change the request timeout (disable it). But on the other hand, it will not be safe if long processing times is not something, that you really except to.

Try this patch or check your web app. If you will provide more information about the servlet/webapp that is causing this issue, it would be easier to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. I observed CPU from last two days it was not that mush high. But as this application is a ESB application which serve some large data transfer service so request can execute more than 15 mins. Tell me one thing 15 mins is ideal time, right?

Comment: It's default, it's hard to say it's ideal :)